# Awk - how to print variable with string

Tags: awk

I have this input and I would like to learn how to save string after = to variable and use it for output filename and in the first line of output that will start with "#"

```
c ROIysiz= 28
c column1= HJD
c RedNumDa= 18262
c column3= ERROR
c column2= FLUX
c end header ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2.458375368952875026e+06 -8.420548421860798386e-04 7.020812100561693928e-03
2.458375579737625085e+06 -5.579159672996818198e-03 1.285380720081348528e-03
2.458376278315599542e+06 -7.634101850411220518e-03 2.481065693991901019e-03
2.458376347386624664e+06 7.223482191697593166e-04 2.319993894372075760e-03
2.458376416108166799e+06 5.238757879614985152e-03 1.389030320490110878e-03
2.458376485913363751e+06 6.777606553373448882e-03 8.887787066666734273e-04
2.458377048675692175e+06 1.950435173388009522e-02 3.242344477396308117e-03
2.458377185153110884e+06 1.885754079806525874e-02 2.090836971653367571e-03
```

Desired output, for instance:

name:
FLUX28ERROR

content:

```
# FLUX 18262
2.458375368952875026e+06 -8.420548421860798386e-04 7.020812100561693928e-03
2.458375579737625085e+06 -5.579159672996818198e-03 1.285380720081348528e-03
2.458376278315599542e+06 -7.634101850411220518e-03 2.481065693991901019e-03
2.458376347386624664e+06 7.223482191697593166e-04 2.319993894372075760e-03
2.458376416108166799e+06 5.238757879614985152e-03 1.389030320490110878e-03
2.458376485913363751e+06 6.777606553373448882e-03 8.887787066666734273e-04
2.458377048675692175e+06 1.950435173388009522e-02 3.242344477396308117e-03
2.458377185153110884e+06 1.885754079806525874e-02 2.090836971653367571e-03
```

I have a script:

```
awk '
/ROIysiz/{
second_out=$NF
}
/column2/{
close(out_file)
found=count=""
out_file=$NF second_out 
next
}
/end header/{
found=1
next
}
found && out_file{
if(++count==1){
print "#" $0 > (out_file)
}
else{
print > (out_file)
}
}
' inputname
```

That gives a file FLUX28:

```
#2.458375368952875026e+06 -8.420548421860798386e-04 7.020812100561693928e-03
2.458375579737625085e+06 -5.579159672996818198e-03 1.285380720081348528e-03
2.458376278315599542e+06 -7.634101850411220518e-03 2.481065693991901019e-03
2.458376347386624664e+06 7.223482191697593166e-04 2.319993894372075760e-03
2.458376416108166799e+06 5.238757879614985152e-03 1.389030320490110878e-03
2.458376485913363751e+06 6.777606553373448882e-03 8.887787066666734273e-04
2.458377048675692175e+06 1.950435173388009522e-02 3.242344477396308117e-03
2.458377185153110884e+06 1.885754079806525874e-02 2.090836971653367571e-03
```

I would like to know how to add another string to filename and how to print the first line of the output:

```
# FLUX 18262
```

I tried it by:

```
awk '
/ROIysiz/{
second_out=$NF
}
/column 3/{
third_part=$NF
}
/column2/{
close(out_file)
found=count=""
out_file=$NF second_out third_part
next
}
/end header/{
found=1
next
}
found && out_file{
if(++count==1){
print "#" second_out third_part > (out_file)
}
else{
print > (out_file)
}
}
' inputname
```

that gives output filename FLUX28 and contains:

```
#28
2.458375579737625085e+06 -5.579159672996818198e-03 1.285380720081348528e-03
2.458376278315599542e+06 -7.634101850411220518e-03 2.481065693991901019e-03
2.458376347386624664e+06 7.223482191697593166e-04 2.319993894372075760e-03
2.458376416108166799e+06 5.238757879614985152e-03 1.389030320490110878e-03
2.458376485913363751e+06 6.777606553373448882e-03 8.887787066666734273e-04
2.458377048675692175e+06 1.950435173388009522e-02 3.242344477396308117e-03
2.458377185153110884e+06 1.885754079806525874e-02 2.090836971653367571e-03
2.458377252462999895e+06 2.159254025049928832e-02 2.315911471112144012e-03
2.458377462405352853e+06 1.721511461149537181e-02 1.687658552459528729e-03
2.458377602279778104e+06 1.744415665326638776e-02 3.041609691486800784e-03
2.458377956590285990e+06 8.597543276201942419e-03 3.490433838852374532e-03
2.458378025015166495e+06 6.127180820289755692e-03 2.437530774283428858e-03
```

Why the variable third_part is not printed in output filename and on the first row? Thank you

Comment: Indentation and white space help a lot to make any program easier to read/understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested code follows:

```
/^c/ { X[$2] = $3 }
/^c end/ { outfile = X["column2="] X["ROIysiz="] X["column3="]
           print "#", X["column2="], X["RedNumDa="] > outfile }
!/^c/ { print $0 >> outfile }
```

**EDIT:** The code is now tested:

```
$ cat x
c ROIysiz= 28
c column1= HJD
c RedNumDa= 18262
c column3= ERROR
c column2= FLUX
c end header ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2.458375368952875026e+06 -8.420548421860798386e-04 7.020812100561693928e-03
2.458375579737625085e+06 -5.579159672996818198e-03 1.285380720081348528e-03
2.458376278315599542e+06 -7.634101850411220518e-03 2.481065693991901019e-03
2.458376347386624664e+06 7.223482191697593166e-04 2.319993894372075760e-03
2.458376416108166799e+06 5.238757879614985152e-03 1.389030320490110878e-03
2.458376485913363751e+06 6.777606553373448882e-03 8.887787066666734273e-04
2.458377048675692175e+06 1.950435173388009522e-02 3.242344477396308117e-03
2.458377185153110884e+06 1.885754079806525874e-02 2.090836971653367571e-03
$ awk '
/^c/ { X[$2] = $3 }
/^c end/ { outfile = X["column2="] X["ROIysiz="] X["column3="]
           print "#", X["column2="], X["RedNumDa="] > outfile }
!/^c/ { print $0 >> outfile }
' x
$ cat FLUX28ERROR
# FLUX 18262
2.458375368952875026e+06 -8.420548421860798386e-04 7.020812100561693928e-03
2.458375579737625085e+06 -5.579159672996818198e-03 1.285380720081348528e-03
2.458376278315599542e+06 -7.634101850411220518e-03 2.481065693991901019e-03
2.458376347386624664e+06 7.223482191697593166e-04 2.319993894372075760e-03
2.458376416108166799e+06 5.238757879614985152e-03 1.389030320490110878e-03
2.458376485913363751e+06 6.777606553373448882e-03 8.887787066666734273e-04
2.458377048675692175e+06 1.950435173388009522e-02 3.242344477396308117e-03
2.458377185153110884e+06 1.885754079806525874e-02 2.090836971653367571e-03
```

The first line, in the `/^c/` pattern, saves each header line (the lines that begin with the letter `c`). The second and third lines, in the `/^c end/` pattern, compute the output filename using string concatenation to join the various header values, then writes the first line of the output file in a similar manner, using the `,` operator to separate fields. The fourth line, in the `!/^c/` pattern, prints each non-header line, unchanged, to the output file. Associative array `X` stores each header key as its index and the associated value at its value.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. On the very first line this will add values of `column2` line, `RedNumDa` line with hash and then with a new line it will print actual line.

```
awk '
/ROIysiz/{
  second_out=$NF
}
/RedNumDa/{
  first_line_value=$NF
}
/c column3/{
  third_part=$NF
}
/column2/{
  close(out_file)
  found=count=""
  first_part=$NF
  out_file=first_part second_out third_part
  next
}
/end header/{
  found=1
  next
}
found && out_file{
  if(++count==1){
    print "#" first_part OFS first_line_value ORS $0 > (out_file)
  }
  else{
    print > (out_file)
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                              ##Starting awk program from here.
/ROIysiz/{                                         ##Checking condition if a line contains string ROIysiz then do following.
  second_out=$NF                                   ##Creating variable second_out for output file 2nd part.
}
/RedNumDa/{                                        ##Checking condition if line contains RedNumDa string in it.
  first_line_value=$NF                             ##Creating variable first_line_value for output file 1st part.
}
/c column3/{                                       ##Checking condition if line contains column 3 string in it.
  third_part=$NF                                   ##Creating variable third_part and setting its value to last field of current line.
}
/column2/{                                         ##Checking condition if line contains column2 string in it.
  close(out_file)                                  ##Closing out_file to avoid "too many files opened" error.
  found=count=""                                   ##Nullifying variable found here.
  first_part=$NF                                   ##Creating variable first_part which has last part of current line as value.
  out_file=first_part second_out third_part        ##Creating variable out_file which is having last field of current line and second_out variable value.
  next                                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/end header/{                                      ##Checking condition if string end header is found then do following.
  found=1                                          ##Setting variable found to 1 here.
  next                                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found && out_file{                                 ##Checking condition if found AND out_file is SET then do following.
  if(++count==1){                                  ##If count==1 then do following, to add # in starting of first line.
     print "#" first_part OFS first_line_value ORS $0 > (out_file)  ##Printing # and first_part OFS first_line_value ORS $0.
  }
  else{                                            ##Else if count is greater than 1 then do following.
    print > (out_file)                             ##Printing current line to out_file here.
  }
}
' Input_file                                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```